# PDO query can't be executed when trying to upload an image to the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add a picture into my mysql databse using the PDO queries. It fails to execute the query and "failed to add the picture" is displayed in the web browser. I get the following error message: Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => ) MySQL error
1
When executing

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$email='test@yahoo.com';
$image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));


$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE user SET driver_img = : driver_img WHERE email = :email ");
        $sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
        $sth->bindParam(':driver_img', $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB); 

        if($sth->execute()) {

                echo "Managed to add the picture.";

            }   
            else {
                echo "failed to add the picture.";
                $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
        die("MySQL error <br>". print_r($arr) ."<br>When executing ");
            }
```

The name of my database table is user. The attributes I am trying to change are called driver_img and email.

Does anyone know what's wrong. Why can't the query be executed?

Comment: The daily mirror .... DON'T store images (binary data) into a database. Just save path and relavant information about the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that `driver_img = : driver_img` shouldn't have that space after the colon.

Comment: That was it.Thank you. I will accept the answer when I am allowed to.